# I Want to list user task in my django Python view

Tags: python-3.x, filter, view, model, grouping

The task can give one group or can give user list.

If someone login the system. Check task status and group and görevli (list). If a user in list or group in user.group.all Show the filtered list.

I didn't make the filtered query

```
    #  todotask = Task.objects.filter(state='to-do').filter(grup__in=request.user.groups.all)

class Task(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Görev")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Görevler")
    STATUSES = (
        ('to-do', _('Yapılacak')),
        ('in_progress', _('Yapılıyor')),
        ('blocked', _('Durduruldu')),
        ('done', _('Tamamlandı')),
        ('dismissed', _('İptal Edildi')),
        ('late', _('Gecikti'))
    )
    PRIORITIES = (
        ('00_low', _('Düşük')),
        ('10_normal', _('Orta')),
        ('20_high', _('Önemli')),
        ('30_critical', _('Çok Önemli')),
        ('40_blocker', _('Engelleyici'))
    )
    title = models.CharField(_("Başlık"), max_length=200)
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT,verbose_name="Dış Ortak")
    proje = models.ForeignKey(Proje, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Proje")
    description = RichTextField("Açıklama", max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    resolution = RichTextField("Sonuç", max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(_("Teslim Tarihi"), null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
    grup = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='task_assigned', verbose_name=_('Atanan Grup'),
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    gorevli = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Atanan Görevliler", related_name='tasks_assigned', null=True,
                                     blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(_("Durum"), max_length=20, choices=STATUSES, default='to-do')
    priority = models.CharField(_("Öncelik"), max_length=20, choices=PRIORITIES, default='10_normal')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='users_created', verbose_name=_('created by'),
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Oluşturulma Zamanı"), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(_("Son Güncelleme"), auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

This filter must return my list.

```
todotask = Task.objects.filter(state='to-do')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   def get_queryset(self, request):
        pusers = []
        liste = []
        projeler = Proje.objects.all()
        for proje in projeler:
            print(proje.title)
            if (proje.grup is not None):
                pusers.append(list(proje.grup.user_set.all()))
            pusers.append(list(proje.gorevli.all()))

            if request.user.username in str(pusers):
                liste.append(proje)
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        gsm = list(liste)
        newqs = Proje.objects.filter(id__in=[o.id for o in gsm])
        if request.user.is_superuser:
          return qs
        else:
            return newqs`enter code here`
```